# Row-wise data from a Polars DataFrame indexable by column name

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I have two CSV files which I have read in and joined. Now I want to iterate through the rows in the resulting DataFrame and interact with various values by their column name. These are small files, and the final DataFrame has fewer than 200 rows in it. So while a performant solution would be nice, I'm much more interested in something that's easy to understand and concise.

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72443329/1749551) which points to `get_row_amortized`. That gets me a Row, but I can't figure out how to get a value from the Row by column name. It's not `get()` or `get_field()`. There's also a warning about how comparitively slow this is, and a column-wise approach with iterators… which doesn't allow indexing by column name.

[This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73319779/1749551) is the cleanest working solution I've found so far. It pulls columns out one at a time, casts them, and then groups the iterators into a single loop. I'm able to use [`izip!()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/macro.izip.html) to do all the columns this way and then destructure the results into a for loop:

```rust
use itertools::izip;

// In my real code this is generated from two joined DFs.
let df = df!(
    "year" => &[1920, 1920, 1920, 1930, 1930],
    "city" => &["Boston", "Memphis", "Columbus", "Boston", "Seattle"],
    "val"  => &[5, 42, 19, 52, 8])?;


let years = df.column("year")?.i64()?;
let cities = df.column("city")?.str()?;
let vals = df.column("val")?.i64()?;

for (year, city, val) in izip!(years, cities, vals)
{
    println!("{:?} {:?} {:?}", year, city, val);
}
```

But this is quite verbose and un-DRY, especially as the number of columns grows.

In reading the docs, I thought that using [the Struct datatype](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/expressions/structs/) would be what I wanted, but again: I can't figure out how to pull out a value by column name. I thought this would "deserialize" each row into a Struct that I make, but it doesn't seem to be working that way.

I'm hoping I'm just missing something and there's a way to do this extremely common operation concisely.

Any help is appreciated!

**Update:** This is available via [`iter_rows()`](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/10811) in Polars for Python. And the Polars team has [ruled out](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/10811) exposing this for Rust.

Comment: `row.0[df.get_column_index("year").unwrap()]`? Since `get_row()` is undidiomatic to begin with I wouldn't expect much support for it.

Comment: Thanks, and that does work. Sadly, it's not much more concise than the `.column()` approach. Do you know if there is a way to get the key-val data out of a DF and into a list which I can then iterate as I want? I've used Polars for this because I thought it would be the easiest way to join two CSVs on a common column, but… maybe it's the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: Are you looking for something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78140756/6699447)?